# How to stop VSCode from autosuggesting after period (comma) in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a way to prevent VSCode from suggesting "%%!" or anything really after periods (comma) inside jupyter notebooks?

This behavior (like in the screenshot below) is really annoying and it doesn't happen in `.py` files.

[image]